# Algorithm for permutation of a configuration setting class

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, combinations, permutation

I've been thinking the solution for my project the whole day that needs to permutate n list of objects according to "step" field inside its class. I have the following class:

```
public class Configuration{
     private String name;
     private int start; //starting value
     private int end;  //ending value
     private int step; //append this to start value until end value is reached
}

//if I have the following sample:
    List<Configuration> configurations = new ArrayList<>();
    Configuration config1 = new Configuration("congif1", 1,2,1);
    Configuration config2 = new Configuration("config2", 100,200,50);
```

I need to implement a method:

```
public Object/void print(List<Configuration> configurations);
```

Such that the expected output would be (in any order as long as the values are complete)

```
1,100
2,100
1,150
2,150
1,200
2,200
```

I need to run through all different configuration scenarios based on user's given configuration setup. If I have 3 objects:

```
Configuration config1 = new Configuration("congif1", 1,2,1);
Configuration config2 = new Configuration("config2", 100,150,50);
Configuration config3 = new Configuration("config3", 1000,2000,500);
```

Then the output should be:

```
1,100,1000
2,100,1000
1,150,1000
2,150,1000
1,100,1500
2,100,1500
1,150,1500
2,150,1500
1,100,2000
2,100,2000
1,150,2000
2,150,2000
```

I tried the following nested loop but it does not permutate all:

```
for(Configuration config:configurations){
     for(int i=start; i<end; i+=step){
          //code here
     }
}
```

I think I need a recursion type for this but I really can't figure out how

Answer (score 0):

First, I should point out that your code is not correct. How are `start`, `end` and `step` defined in your loop? How can you access them?

Next, I would add getters and a method to do a permutation between two configurations to your class `Configuration` much like:

```
public class Configuration {

     private String name;
     private int start;
     private int end;
     private int step;
     
     public Configuration(...) { // Some constructor }

     public int getStart() { return start; }

     public int getEnd() { return end; }

     public int getStep() { return step; }

     public void permutateWith(Configuration c) {
          for(int i = start; i <= end; i += step) {
               for(int j = c.getStart(); j <= c.getEnd(); j += c.getStep()) {
                    System.out.println(i + "," + j);
               }
          }
     }

}
```

With this class in place, we can create two instances:

```
Configuration config1 = new Configuration("congif1", 1,2,1);
Configuration config2 = new Configuration("config2", 100,200,50);
```

and ad them to a list:

```
List<Configuration> configurations = new ArrayList<>();
configurations.add(config1);
configurations.add(config2);
```

Now, you can write a method `printPermutations(List<Configuration> list)` such as:

```
private void printPermutations(List<Configuration> list) {
     
     // Pick one element
     for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
          // Combine with all the others
          for(int j = i + 1; j < list.length; j++) {
               list.get(i).permutateWith(list.get(j));
          }
     }
}
```

I haven't tried myself but should solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for you quick response. I already  tried it and it works as I expected for 2 objects. However not for n objects. Can you please help me again... I updated my question to add 3 configurations in a list and its exptected output :praying

Answer (score 0):

***Note:** this became longer than I anticipated. If you want the TLDR of the answer, go down to the "3rd block" section.*

Hey I think I got it. I used some of your code and with the help of @YodaAndFriends's answer here is my recursive solution.

I will seperate my answer to a few blocks of codes, to describe each one of them more clrealy.

**1st block:**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Configuration {

    private String name;
    private int start;
    private int end;
    private int step;
     
    public Configuration(String name, int start, int end, int step) {
        this.name = name;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.step = step;
    }

    public int getStart() {return start;}

    public int getEnd() {return end;}

    public int getStep() {return step;}
    
    public void setStart(int num) {this.start = num;}
```

Basic class configurations (with obvious List/ArrayList imports). This should be identical to @YodaAndFriends part, I just added a `setStart` method.

**2nd block:**

```
    public static void printStarters(List<Configuration> configurations) {
        System.out.printf("%d",configurations.get(0).getStart());
        for(int i=1; i<configurations.size(); i++) {
            System.out.printf(", %d",configurations.get(i).getStart());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    
    public static boolean endPoint(List<Configuration> configurations) {
        for(int i=0; i<configurations.size(); i++) {
            if (configurations.get(i).getStart() != configurations.get(i).getEnd()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Here I wrote some helper methods:

- `printStarters` to simply print the current *starts* of all the configurations within each recursion.
- `endPoint` is checking wether we reached the end of the recursion and each of the *starts* is equal to it's *end* respectively.

**3rd block:**

```
public static void printPermutations(List<Configuration> configurations) {
        int[] starters = new int[configurations.size()];
        for(int i=0; i<configurations.size(); i++) {
            starters[i] = configurations.get(i).getStart();
        }
        printStarters(configurations);
        printPermutations(configurations, starters, 0);
    }
    
    private static void printPermutations(List<Configuration> configurations, int[] starters, int y) {
        if (endPoint(configurations)) {
            return;
        }
        Configuration current = configurations.get(y);
        if (current.getStart() != current.getEnd()) {
            current.setStart(current.getStart() + current.getStep());
            printStarters(configurations);
            printPermutations(configurations, starters, 0);
        }
        else {
            current.setStart(starters[y]);
            printPermutations(configurations, starters, ++y);
        }
    }
```

This is the actual solution method. `printPermutations` is overloaded and the first variation is calling the second one.

- The first `printPermutations` is setting an int array of *starts* to reset *starts* that have reached their respective *ends*. It then calls the next variation of `printPermutations`.
- The second (private) variation is the recursive one, it recieves the array of *starts*, and an index `y` in addition to the Configurations list.

**How it works:** It first check if we reached the `endPoint`.

**If** the *start* of the *current configuration* (in accordance to index `y`) is different than it's *end*, we increase it by *step*, call `printStarters`, and recursively call the function **back to the first configuration of the list** (`y = 0`).

**Else** the *start* is equal to it's *end* -> we reset it to it's original *start* value, and call the function on the **next configuration of the list**.

---

Hope this wasn't too much explaination, I tried to be as clear as possible. I tested this code together with 3 configs as such:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Configuration> c = new ArrayList<>();
        Configuration config1 = new Configuration("congif1", 1,2,1);
        Configuration config2 = new Configuration("config2", 100,150,50);
        Configuration config3 = new Configuration("config3", 1000,2000,500);
        c.add(config1);
        c.add(config2);
        c.add(config3);
        printPermutations(c);
    }
}
```

If you copy all of my code blocks one after the other, it should work perfectly fine. There might be ways to reduce time/memory complexity, but this is what I came up with.